# How to perform a database operation when onMessageReceived is triggered?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-room

I'm trying to update my `Room` database when Firebase Cloud Messaging executes `onMessageReceived`.

The problem comes when my app is closed, because in this scenario, my database connection is not created yet, so this throws an Exception.

I'm creating the Room database connection instance from `MainActivity` which is launched every time that user launch the application, using this line:

```
db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database").build();
```

This `db` var is public and static, so normally I access it from anywhere in my app, since always is available.

But, in this situation is not available, I also tried, with no success, to create a new connection instance from `onMessageReceived`, but it's not posible since I can't use `getApplicationContext()` method, because there are no Activity.

There are any workaround?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onMessageReceived` is a method in `FirebaseMessagingService` which is obviously a service. 
And a service is also a context. So it is not a must to use your MainActivity as the context.

In your `onMessageReceived` method, simply use:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase.class, "database").build();
```

Comment: use Context of onMessageReceived method to open database.